# Gitlab always exited automatically

Tags: docker, gitlab

I am running the gitlab with docker, but it always exits after a period of time

```
==> /var/log/gitlab/redis/current <==
2019-06-21_18:00:08.72435 459:signal-handler (1561140008) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...
2019-06-21_18:00:08.81864 459:M 21 Jun 18:00:08.817 # User requested shutdown...
2019-06-21_18:00:08.81866 459:M 21 Jun 18:00:08.817 * Saving the final RDB snapshot before exiting.
2019-06-21_18:00:08.83736 459:M 21 Jun 18:00:08.837 * DB saved on disk
2019-06-21_18:00:08.83741 459:M 21 Jun 18:00:08.837 * Removing the pid file.
2019-06-21_18:00:08.83817 459:M 21 Jun 18:00:08.838 * Removing the unix socket file.
2019-06-21_18:00:08.83935 459:M 21 Jun 18:00:08.839 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
ok: down: redis-exporter: 0s, normally up

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sidekiq.log <==
2019-06-21_18:00:09.57615 2019-06-21T18:00:09.576Z 807 TID-oviw2sgmf INFO: Shutting down
2019-06-21_18:00:09.57625 2019-06-21T18:00:09.576Z 807 TID-ovivo05i7 INFO: Scheduler exiting...
2019-06-21_18:00:09.57655 2019-06-21T18:00:09.576Z 807 TID-oviw2sgmf INFO: Terminating quiet workers
```

Comment: Probably something is sending a `SIGTERM` in your case?

Comment: Maybe..but I want to know how fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was reported in [`gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab` issue 4137](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/4137): "`runsv` send `SIGTERM` to redis in docker version"

> `runsv` sends SIGTERM to redis every 60 secs

[gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab issue 1611](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/1611) suggests a `docker restart` first.
But the general issue is not conclusively resolved yet.